# Conditional expectation and estimator

Tags: statistics, expectation, poisson-process

Let $\mu,\alpha_n:\mathbb R^+\to \mathbb R$ continuous function with $\mu$ bounded function.
Let $N^{(n)}$ the trajectory of a Poisson process with intensity $(\alpha_n \mu)(t)$.
Let $0=T_0^{(n)}<T_1^{(n)}<\dots$ jumps of $N^{(n)}$.

Let $M_n(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{N_t^{(n)}} \frac {1} {\alpha_n (T_i^{(n)})}$ and $M(t)=\int_0^t \mu(s)ds$.

Calculate $E((M_n(t)-M(t))^2)$?

I don't have any idea. I tried to develop $E\left(\left(M_n(t)-M(t)\right)^2\right)$ but it's not good.